How can you turn a specific LED on a strip on depending on a characters from a string?
I am using a Wrover ESP32 Module and WS2811 lights. I am writing code to turn on LED's depending on letters in a string. Eventually I want to get user input to be the string, but that's irrelevant to my issue at the moment. I have written serialprints in order to troubleshoot and each value in the string prints out when called in the switch statement, but the lights won't turn on when I call for it in the switch statement. I have used other code I have found on github and the lights do work properly when the code is written properly.
#include <FastLED.h>
#define DATA_PIN 18  
#define NUM_LEDS 26 
#define COLOR_ORDER RGB

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS]; 

char var[27] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  FastLED.clear();
  FastLED.show();
  delay(8000);
  Serial.println("Starting setup...");
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2811, DATA_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS); 

}

void loop(){
  Serial.println(var);
    
  for (int i = 0; i <= 26; i++) {
    char letter = var[i];
    ITERATE(letter);
  }

}


void ITERATE(char letter) {
  FastLED.clear();
  FastLED.show();
  switch(letter){
    case 'a':
      leds[0] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("a");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'b':
      leds[1] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("b");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'c':
      leds[2] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("c");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'd':
      leds[3] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("d");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'e':
      leds[4] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("e");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'f':
      leds[5] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("f");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'g':
      leds[6] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("g");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'h':
      leds[7] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("h");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'i':
      leds[8] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("i");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'j':
      leds[9] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("j");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'k':
      leds[10] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("k");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'l':
      leds[11] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("l");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'm':
      leds[12] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("m");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'n':
      leds[13] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("n");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'o':
      leds[14] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("o");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'p':
      leds[15] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("p");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'q':
      leds[16] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("q");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'r':
      leds[17] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("r");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 's':
      leds[18] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("s");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 't':
      leds[19] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("t");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'u':
      leds[20] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("u");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'v':
      leds[21] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("v");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'w':
      leds[22] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("w");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'x':
      leds[23] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("x");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'y':
      leds[24] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("y");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    case 'z':
      leds[25] = CRGB (0,255,255);
      FastLED.show();
      Serial.println("z");
      delay(1000);
      break;
    default:
      FastLED.clear();
  }
    
  FastLED.show();
  FastLED.clear(); 
}

I'm sure there is a much better way to go about doing this, if you have any suggestions please feel free to send them my way. I am just curious why the serial print statements work but the FastLED.show() after setting the LED value doesn't.
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z

This is the output
Thank you

Not sure this is your problem, but calling clear() and show() before addLeds<...>() looks suspicious to me.

there is no reason to use Serial.println("a"); inside the case block ... use Serial.println(letter); in all case blocks ... now do you see how you can simplify your code?

Please try to light up a single fixed LED at the end of setup(). Does that work as expected? (This step can narrow down the problem further)

I think you might have the wrong pin assignment or hardware connection issue. As far as I can tell, the code (although could be reduced significantly) work perfectly fine as it supposed to do (i.e. sequence through the LED based on each character within the var every 1 second).

Hey Edgar, just after I posted this code, I removed the show() just before the addLeds portion and it allowed me to clear the led strip. I am still confused on this however becuase from what I have read, even if you clear the leds, it won't turn them off until you tell the leds to show that they have been cleared, but it works to not have show so I won't complain there.

fair enough jsotola, I wasn't thinking about that when writing the code, however since the individual cases were still reached I don't think its an issue of the letter character, I should still get the same output on the serial monitor right?

chrisl I will do that as soon as possible and come back with the results. I appreciate that idea!

hcheung I was thinking the same thing potentially but I ran code that would simultaneously turn on the first 30 leds and have them be different colors and that didn't have any issues communicating to the individual leds.

hcheung The other code that I have tested only calls FastLED.show() after setting all of the leds to their designated light values. Could it be an issue of the program trying to do too much on my end? I know that arduinos can handle a decent bit of load, but its the only thing I can think of at the moment.
